# What is meant by "Fox Two"?

Tags: military, radio-communications, terminology, missiles

Numerous Movies, Video Games, and TV shows featuring fighter pilots depict the pilots calling out "Fox Two" on the radio as they fire a missile.

The transmission (as depicted, I'm not sure about IRL) frequently does not include the aircraft identifier (tailnumber or callsign). (but sometimes an aircraft ID is included)

What does this signify? Why is it important? And why is the term "Fox Two" rather than any other variation of "Missile Fired"/"Missile Away"?

How are other pilots meant to respond when they hear "Fox Two" on the radio?

Answer (score 41):

Fox codes are used by NATO military aircraft to designate a release of an air-to-air munition, generally missiles.

[Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_(code_word)) One is a [semi-active radar guided missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-active_radar_homing), for example the [AIM-7 Sparrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIM-7_Sparrow). This type of missile requires the radar of the launching aircraft to guide it to its target.

Fox Two is an [infrared-guided missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_homing), for example the [AIM-9 Sidewinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIM-9_Sidewinder). This missile is ["fire and forget"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire-and-forget).

Fox Three is an [active radar guided missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_radar_homing), for example the [AIM-120 AMRAAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIM-120_AMRAAM). This missile has its own radar to track the target; it is "fire and forget".

Fox Four is guns. Previously this was Fox Three.

You can find all the acronyms and brevity codes in the [Field Manual 1-02-1](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/library/policy/army/fm/3-54-10/fm3-54-10.pdf) on page 33 of the PDF.

Comment: Good to know there are other kinds of "Foxes", that aren't frequently shown in fiction.  However, why does it need to be called out at all?  What're you supposed to do when you hear that from your fellow pilots? For AAR purposes, wouldn't the flight recorder and other data sources show what weapon was fired at what time at which target?

Comment: @abelenky - "What're you supposed to do when you hear that from your fellow pilots?" Don't get between the missile and its intended target. Otherwise, it may lock on to YOU.

Comment: @WPNSGuy: Scenes from "Top Gun: Maverick" not withstanding, it is virtually impossible for a friendly craft to maneuver fast enough to get in front of an un-intended missile even deliberately, much less accidentally.  It is also the responsibility of the Pilot firing the missile to fire only when the target path is clear of friendlies.

Comment: Seeing as there have been documented air to air kills from 28km, Turkish F-16 v Syrian MiG....doesn't seem to unlikely to me. 28km is about 30 seconds flight time for an AMRAAM. That sounds like a lot of space and time.

Comment: @WPNSGuy "How do friendly-fire incidents happen?" sounds like a separate question.

Comment: @abelenky In movies it's Fox 2 because that's what you would fire in a dogfight--and in the movies it's a dogfight for drama.  Radar guided missiles are typically used in reasonably long range engagements that are blips on the radar--not much for the silver screen.

Comment: @abelenky I wouldn't say it's impossible--if you're already near the target getting in the way of the missile is certainly possible.

Comment: One great reason to announce the launch of a missile and the type is so that your wing and flight and command are aware of your remaining weapons load. They also would all know the number of bandits and approximate range of engagement. This keeps the situational awareness up for everyone, which means everyone can make informed decisions. "Guns guns guns" is also called when guns are used. Combined with "splash one" for kills, the radio alone can be an effective situational awareness tool.

Comment: @abelenky on the 'why do weapon launch brevity words exist in general' is that often launches are made to another orders, so the codeword is your 'I have complied with your command, now doing the next thing'. In the world of equipment from the lowest bidder can also mean 'all my technology worked, backup weapons can be reprioritized'. Finally it also means 'any command to NOT kill this target is now irrelevant'.

Comment: There's also an unofficial joke that "Fox 4" is [using the aircraft itself as a weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_ramming) (ref: [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/rec.aviation.military/c/ww1lj9-1jVU/m/HwyUNBhUwoMJ), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dcsworld/comments/wwbq7n/almost_got_hit_with_a_fox4/))

Comment: And it seems to me that "Fox" stands for the letter "F" (maybe in turn for "fire/firing"). So the number following is the category of what has being launched/fired.

Comment: I'm fairly sure most modern (at least NATO standard missiles) have IFF capabilities no?

Comment: @U.Windl Specifically "Fox" is short for "Foxtrot", which is the NATO phoenetic code for the letter "F", and yes it does mean "Fire".  This should probably be added in the answer, but you can see it on the Wikipedia link under the word "Fox".

Comment: @abelenky I seem to recall at least one incident of an aircraft shooting *itself*. With guns. So, friendly fire might not be as farfetched of a possibility as you'd think.

Comment: @reirab It was a F11F Tiger, in 1956, during a live-fire cannon test in a Mach 1 dive. The bullets were slowed down by drag and the plane was going so fast that it shot itself. The pilot had to ditch. It happened with a F14 in 1973 and a F16 in 2009.

Comment: @Benson_YoureFired If the pilots were allowed to continue flying, I wonder whether their crews painted silhouettes of their previous aircraft on their next one?

Answer (score 2):

A heat seeker won't "ping" the defender's radar, and since the launch is simulated you won't see a smoke trail either. In a training situation saying "Fox 2" on the radio tells the defender that there is a simulated missile in the air, and cues them to simulate popping flares and maneuvering to defend against the missile.

Comment: But "Fox Two" is also used for *actual* launches, not just simulated ones.

Comment: It is?  Do you know this for a fact?  (you reference "Numerous Movies, Video Games, and TV shows...")

Comment: @Michael Hall - Yes, it is used in real munitions release as well. From Wiki "Fox is a brevity code used by NATO pilots to signal the simulated or actual release of an air-to-air munition or other combat function."  Also, from personal discussions with USAF pilots over the years.

Comment: *"It is? Do you know this for a fact?"* I'm referencing the document linked by @Benson_YoureFired in his answer, which appears to be an authoritative document.

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks!  Something in my distant memory recalls hearing that you wouldn't announce your attack to the enemy, but I can also see some benefit for AWACS, wingman, etc.

Comment: I certainly hope in a real battle, your communications are fully encrypted and the enemy cannot hear your call.  You certainly wouldn't make the call on UNICOM or CTAF! (hah)

Comment: Indeed that would be true!

Comment: @abelenky unless you are lying to throw your enemy off (ha!)

Comment: @Michael, on more than one occasion I have seen your comments and thought "I don't remember saying that..."!

Comment: @MichaelHall I have done that on more than one occasion with various other Michaels, but not when they have a last name attached :)